# Difference between mutate and transmute in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm relatively new to R and am working with the dplyr package for data manipulation. I've come across functions like mutate and transmute and I'm a bit confused about their differences. I understand that both are used for creating or modifying variables in a data frame, but can someone explain the key distinctions between them? Additionally, in what situations would one be preferred over the other? I appreciate any insights or examples that can help clarify their usage. Thank you!

Comment: `mutate()` keeps all variables in the original dataframe (unless otherwise specified in the `.keep` argument.) `transmute()` returns a dataframe with only the newly computed or modified variables.

Comment: do this both:`mtcars %>% 
  mutate(this_is_new = 1:n())

mtcars %>% 
  transmute(this_is_new = 1:n())` and you will understand!

Comment: `mtcars |> mutate(a = 1, .keep = "none")` and `mtcars |> transmute(a = 1)` are equivalent